# Not working this if statement on android (Java)

Tags: java, android, if-statement

Im trying to compare the versionName of my android app located in the build.grade with the version that takes from a external database.

My script is this:

```
version.add(jsonarray_appdata.getJSONObject(i).getString("version"));
                        String versionName = BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME;
                        String str = version.toString();
                        versionName = "[" + versionName + "]";
                        if(versionName != str){
                            Intent intent2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Update.class);
                            startActivity(intent2);
                            finish();
                        } else {
                            Thread myThread = new Thread() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    try {
                                        sleep(3000);
                                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                                        startActivity(intent);
                                        finish();
                                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                            };
                            myThread.start();
                        }
```

The versionName value is "[1.3]" and the str value is "[1.3]".
So the values are the same but it never goes to the else {} condition.

I tried removing the [ ] of both, and not working.

There are no blank spaces in the values.

Any idea what is happening?

Thanks!

Comment: You are comparing strings the wrong way in `versionName != str`. You should use `equals`.

Comment: Thank you both. A noob fail from a PHP programmer. `if(!versionName.equals(str)){`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to compare strings, and `versionName != str` is not how you do it, you are just comparing references.

Change

```
versionName != str
```

To

```
versionName.equalsIgnoreCase(str)
```